# how to select from finger not standard columns

Tags: file, bash, sed, awk

i have a file that i got with finger command, and i want to keep only name, surname and access point of the user. The problem is that some users are idle and they have one extra column, so the access point column is not standard so that i can use awk print $z.

Is there any way i could do that?

I thought afterwards if i could select that extra field and remove it later with `sed` or `awk` but how? As you can see some lines have the idle time that i have selected with finger and some don't cause the users haven't been idle. I just wanna keep names surnames and access points. Thnx!

The file is like this :

```
Name1 surname1 22:04 (athedsl-xxxxxxxxx.home.otenet.gr)
Name2 surname2 (xxxxxxxxxx.dsl.hol.gr)
.
.
.
```

and so on...

Comment: finger?  this is still around?  what a throwback ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know sed/awk but you can do this with a perl one-liner:

```
cat file | perl -ne 'if (/(\w+)\s+(\w+).*\((.*)\)/) { print "$1 $2 $3\n" }'
```

Perl is on virtually all *nix systems these days so hopefully it'll work for you.  With the data you gave, you get:

```
bob surname1 athedsl-xxxxxxxxx.home.otenet.gr
john surname2 xxxxxxxxxx.dsl.hol.gr
```

Comment: try again now I've edited it, I was a little too literalistic with your example data...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways:

```
awk '{gsub(/^\(|\)$/, "", $NF); print $1, $2, $NF}'

awk 'NF == 4 {$3 = ""}1'
```

The second one leaves the parentheses in place and leaves an extra space in place of the idle time, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with the `finger` command, but I think you can solve this using `awk` like this:

`finger | awk 'NR >= 2 { gsub ("[\\(|\\)]","",$NF); print $1"\t"$3"\t"$NF }'`

HTH

Comment: Replace `"\t"` with `,` in the print statement if you don't like tab-sep vals.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
finger | sed '/\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\s*\)\?(\([^)]*\))$/!d;s//\2/'
Name1 surname1 athedsl-xxxxxxxxx.home.otenet.gr
Name2 surname2 xxxxxxxxxx.dsl.hol.gr
```